# Save the state of the web after refresh it automatically

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that's used to chat with helpers, if one of them is chatting or busy it shows the state of busy and it's not possible to chat but it's possible to send him a message.

The problem comes when someone is filling the form and the web page is refreshed to update the state of the helpers, here the form and the data that the user was writing is lost.

I would like to know is exists a way to save the state of the web page and if the user was filling the form, show it with the data he entered.

I thought to use sessions, cookies or redo the system to don't reload the whole page.

Which can be the best way?

Comment: best is a matter of perspective. Look into local storage though. You can save the state of fields on keyup if you want and keep them in a stored object

Comment: It difficult to answer with anything other then yes, it is possible and that the best way depends on a lot of factors. What browsers are you supporting, what technologies are you using, is the site desktop, mobile, tablet etc. you skill level also has a baring. You'd be better of researching and prototyping a few to see what best fits you needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookies in javascript to save input value whenever the user change it and put it with php

```
<input type="text" name="msg" onkeyup="document.cookie='msg='+this.value" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['msg'])) echo $_COOKIE['msg']?>">
```